# Configure Squid Proxy Server to Use e2Guardian in Blocking Specific Sites

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, slackware, dansguardian

I have successfully installed and configured Squid Proxy Server. I have to block site like Facebook.com using e2guardian. Unfortunately, I could not find any reliable comprehensive documentation how to use it with Squid Proxy. If anyone could point me into the right direction, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to block access to facebook without actually looking into contents then just use squid acl to do that. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943381/how-to-block-website-using-squid-server shall do the trick.